# drawRect is not being called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, drawrect

I need to draw an image in a rectangle so for that am using drawRect method.i observed that it is not being called.The output i can see only the blank screen.Am using MAC OS and i need to test the App in Iphone OS 3+.Please can anyone solve my problem.Here is my code:

```
    -(IBAction)calling
  {
 int a=0;
 a=a+1;
 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];  //InRect:CGRectMake(78, 43, 200, 138)];

  }

 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btbp.jpg"];

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400);

    [myImage drawInRect:imageRect];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];

    [myImage release];
 }
```

i donno where i was wrong:(

Answer (score 2):

1. Is your `drawRect` method on an actual view? Or is it on the view controller, which is what it seems like? `drawRect` is something you write/override on the view itself.
2. You should not call `release` on the `myImage` object, since you didn't `alloc` it yourself.

If this isn't making 100% sense, I'd recommend you start with the iOS Cocoa Views documentation to understand how this all fits together.

Comment: actually my application is a viewbased one.Am implementing it in a subclass of uiviewcontroller.Am writing the drawRect .Yes am drawing it on actual view.You suggested some document where can i find it

Comment: The -drawRect: method must be implemented on a subclass of UIView, not on your view controller.  Note,also, that calling setNeedsDisplay from your drawRect method is a very bad idea indeed.

Comment: @iphoneStruggler: I understand what you're trying to do, but you should work through some tutorials online about basic Cocoa apps, or grab one of the intro-to-iPhone books. There's some basic stuff here to get right that may be beyond the scope of Stack Overflow to answer all of. Here's some docs about custom views: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW13